Problems with Ubuntu 23.10 on Asus Vivobook 16(X1605VA-MB957WS)
I'm using Ubuntu 23.10 on Asus Vivobook 16(X1605VA-MB957WS) and have the following problem:
The wifi card in the laptop Mediatek wifi card whose driver doesn't support the kernel of Ubuntu. So I don't have Wifi. Can anyone suggest a good external wifi adapter so that I can have wifi on my laptop?
Output of lshw -C network is:
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff memory:6000000000-60000fffff memory:84000000-84007fff

Output of lspci | grep -i network is:
0000:02:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7902

I saw an online post claiming that TP-Link USB Wifi TL-WN725N works but that adapter doesn't have a driver for kernel>4.4.3 so I'm not sure if it'll work or not.

https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:14c3-7902-1a3b-5520 -> No solution unfortunately. You can replace it by any Intel, Atheros and most Realtek based WiFi card for the same price or less than USB ones.

@ChanganAuto Can do that surely but do you know of any external wifi adapters I can use? I don't want to change my wifi card as to not damage my warranty.

Please note that hardware recommendation requests (eg "Can anyone suggest a good external wifi adapter so that I can have wifi on my laptop?") are explicitly off topic on this site. You can edit your post to remove this part and focus on an on-topic question.
